# Replace all text after special character

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I have the following string for example

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518282/regex-to-find-all-text-after-delimited-string?3748374731`

I want to try to use regex to place all the items after the `?` - so I am just left with the raw URL?

I am trying to do this with javascript ?

Comment: What language are you using?  I'm willing to bet there are built in URI parsers

Comment: sorry - javascript is the language!

Comment: what do you mean by "place all the items"?

Answer (score 3):

```
var url="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518282/regex-to-find-all-text-after-delimited-string?3748374731";
var path=url.split("?")[0];
```

Comment: You and your answers that are more elegant than mine!

Comment: ah the only problem - are you able to do it so its always the last one ?

Comment: @Andy In which case would it NOT be the first one?

Comment: Hush @Christophe he doesn't need to know that! ------ Sorry it's been a long day...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
<? $string = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518282/regex-to-find-all-text-after-delimited-string?3748374731' ;
$string = substr ( $string , 0 , strpos ( $string , '?' ) ) ;
echo $string ;
?>
```

Update: javascript huh?

almost the same thing:

```
var string = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518282/regex-to-find-all-text-after-delimited-string?3748374731' ;
string = string.substr(0,string.search('?');
```

Answer (score 0):

something like...

```
function removeParams(url) {
    return url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('?'));
}
```

would work. It takes the substring of url from 0 to the last occurence of a question mark and returns it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just grab all characters before the ? and ignore the rest, assuming the ? only occurs once (should be the case, ?'s within the url should be url-encoded)

```
^[^?]+
```

^ matches from start of string. [^?] means anything not a question mark. + means the previous character class 1 or more times.

You could also do

```
var s = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518282/regex-to-find-all-text-after-delimited-string?3748374731";
var rawUrl = s.split("?")[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

`document.location.origin+document.location.pathname`